# How to prove that $x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2 \leq \frac{1}{3}$ where $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$ and $x,y,z >0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials

How to prove that $x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2 \leq \frac{1}{3}$ where $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$ and $x,y,z >0$?

Comment: Hint:  use Lagrange multiplies to find maximize your test function subject to the given constraint.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices, and [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960) and the others there for information on writing a good question for this site. In particular, people will be more willing to help if you edit your question to include some motivation, and an explanation of your own attempts. In addition, [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics.

Comment: To elicit a response please include shortly how you went about solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the inequality as 
$$
xyz(x+y+z)\leq\frac13. 
$$
On the left-hand-side, using Cauchy-Schwarz, 
$$
xyz(x+y+z)\leq xyz(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}(1+1+1)^{1/2}=\sqrt3\,xyz. 
$$
Now we get the seemingly easier problem of maximizing $xyz$ under $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Here symmetry, common sense, or Lagrange multipliers show that the maximum is achieved when $x=y=z$. Then 
$$
xyz(x+y+z)\leq xyz(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{1/2}(1+1+1)^{1/2}=\sqrt3\,xyz\leq\frac{\sqrt3}{(\sqrt3)^3}=\frac13. 
$$

Answer (score 3):

By [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) with

- $u=(x,y,z)$
- $v=(xyz,xyz,xyz)$

we have

$$u\cdot v\le |u|\cdot |v|$$

that is

$$x^2yz+xy^2z+xyz^2 \leq\sqrt3\,xyz \le \frac{1}{3}$$

indeed by [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)

$$\frac13=\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}\ge \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}\implies xyz \le\frac{1}{3\sqrt3}$$

Answer (score 1):

It's true even for all reals $x$, $y$ and $z$.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)^2\geq3xyz(x+y+z)$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^4+2x^2y^2-3x^2yz)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(2x^4+4x^2y^2-6x^2yz)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x^4-2x^2y^2+y^4+3z^2x^2-6z^2xy+3z^2y^2)\geq0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2((x+y)^2+3z^2)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Comment: Good point Michael, that's correct also by CS inequality (which holds for all reals) and AM-GM since we deal with $x^2$,$y^2$,$z^2$.

Comment: Yes, of course. I think the SOS also seems nice.

Comment: How can you handle the inequalities in this way, as it was a simple task? I could not see that in terms of SOS!

Comment: Yes, of course, this problem is simple, but I always try to use SOS because it's very useful method.

Comment: I would like to use but I can't see and handle inequalities how you did, I'm not sufficiently aware and skilled about it!